# Trying to remove headers via vba but get run-time error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the Run time error 91 "Object variable or with block variable not set" with this line of code. What is stumping me is that sometimes it runs perfectly and others it just gives me the error. When I searched that error everything seemed to be in place. I am trying to remove rows with duplicate headers and rows that are populated by zeros. Can anyone seem to find the problem with it?

```
    Sub RemoveHeaders()
Const HdrTextOne As String = "*Station*"
Const HdrTextTwo As String = "*Export File For Future Analysis*"
Const HdrTextThree As String = "*0*"
Const HdrKeepRowOne As Long = 3
Const HdrKeepRowTwo As Long = 1
Const HdrKeepRowThree As Long = 19
Dim c As Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("B" & HdrKeepRowOne & ":B" & lr)
    Set c = .Find(HdrTextOne, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowOne Then
        Do
            c.Resize(5).EntireRow.Delete
            Set c = .Find(HdrTextOne, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowOne
    End If
End With

 lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("B" & HdrKeepRowTwo & ":B" & lr)
    Set c = .Find(HdrTextTwo, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowTwo Then
        Do
            c.Resize(5).EntireRow.Delete
            Set c = .Find(HdrTextTwo, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowTwo
    End If
End With

 lr = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("D" & HdrKeepRowThree & ":D" & lr)
    Set c = .Find(HdrTextThree, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowThree Then
        Do
            c.Resize(5).EntireRow.Delete
            Set c = .Find(HdrTextThree, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowThree
    End If
End With
ws.Columns("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Try setting `Set c = Nothing` after the highlighted `If` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with the suggested adjustment (as written in the comment) and a few more minor changes. The code has been tested and works fine on my system.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveHeaders()

Const HdrTextOne As String = "*Station*"
Const HdrTextTwo As String = "*Export File For Future Analysis*"
Const HdrTextThree As String = "*0*"
Const HdrKeepRowOne As Long = 3
Const HdrKeepRowTwo As Long = 1
Const HdrKeepRowThree As Long = 19

Dim c As Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Data", vbTextCompare) Then
        MsgBox "Using the sheet:" & Chr(10) & "'" & ws.Name & "'"
        Exit For
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet not found." & Chr(10) & "Aborting!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

If lr > HdrKeepRowThree Then
    With ws.Range("B" & HdrKeepRowOne & ":B" & lr)
        Set c = .Find(HdrTextOne, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowOne Then
            Do
                c.Resize(5).EntireRow.Delete
                Set c = .Find(HdrTextOne, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowOne
        End If
        Set c = Nothing


        Set c = .Find(HdrTextTwo, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowTwo Then
            Do
                c.Resize(5).EntireRow.Delete
                Set c = .Find(HdrTextTwo, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowTwo
        End If
        Set c = Nothing
    End With
End If

lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

If lr > HdrKeepRowThree Then
    With ws.Range("D" & HdrKeepRowThree & ":D" & lr)
        Set c = .Find(HdrTextThree, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowThree Then
            Do
                c.Resize(5).EntireRow.Delete
                Set c = .Find(HdrTextThree, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> HdrKeepRowThree
        End If
        Set c = Nothing
    End With
End If

On Error GoTo NoBlanksFound
ws.Columns("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

NoBlanksFound:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note, that the `Find` method does not support wildcards such as `*`. If you wish to find a partial string then you should change your `Find` to `LookAt:=xlPart` [as stipulated on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

Let me know if this solves your problems.

Comment: I am still getting the same error using the posted code. I will try changing the wild cards and run again

Comment: Are you sure that the sheet name is `Data` and not possibly `Data ` (with a trailing space or something)? That would typically lead to the error code you are getting. I just changed the code to check for that error. Please give it a try.

Comment: Giving me a "Sheet not found, Aborting" message. The sheet is automatically created with the name "Data" no spaces.

Comment: Just what I thought. There is no sheet with the name `Data` in your Excel file. I just adjusted the code to use the first sheet that has "Data" in its name instead. Let me know if this works now.

Comment: Same error. Here is the code i use to create my data. Maybe that will shed some light on the naming.

Comment: With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.name = "Data"
    End With

Comment: If the above code stops with `Sheet not found.` then there is no sheet by the name of `Data` in your Excel file. There could be many reasons: (1) The code generating the new sheet is run after the above code or not yet run, (2) the code generating a new sheet is run in a different workbook, (3) you have a Cyrillic keyboard layout and the `a` in `Data` is mixed with Latin characters, (4) and many more... All I can say is that the above code proves (!) that there is no sheet by the name `Data` in your Excel file at the time the code is run.